# POP3 Account suddenly cannot receive emai through SMTP l when used on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, email, pop3, windows-mail

I was using my ISP's POP3 email account with Windows Live Mail on Windows Vista. Today I upgraded to Windows 7 using a upgrade disk but using a custom install.
Before upgrading I exported my email account settings and messages. When I upgraded I downloaded Windows Live Mail 2011 and imported my account and emails.

Now I can send emails from the account, however when I attemt to send a message to the account I receive a mail delivery error (in this case in Gmail).

> Delivery to the following recipient
>   failed permanently:
>
> {email_address}
>
> Technical details of permanent
>   failure: Google tried to deliver your
>   message, but it was rejected by the
>   recipient domain. We recommend
>   contacting the other email provider
>   for further information about the
>   cause of this error. The error that
>   the other server returned was: 550
>   550-5.1.1 The email account that you
>   tried to reach does not exist. Please
>   try 550-5.1.1 double-checking the
>   recipient's email address for typos or
>   550-5.1.1 unnecessary spaces. Learn
>   more at 550 5.1.1
>   http://mail.Google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=6596
>   14si1022989ibb.65 (state 14).

I know that I have the email address spelled correctly because I tried replying to a email sent from my account.

Please advise as I do not understand why there would be such problems as I have not made any changes to my email account on the server.

Comment: Could you clarify which direction are you sending the message in? From Gmail to ISPmail or vice versa? The error message you pasted looks like it's being sent _to_ Gmail, but you say the opposite.

Comment: (FYI, this is not related to POP3 (which is only for fetching mail from your ISP). The error occurs when attempting to send the mail over SMTP.)

Comment: @grawity, apologies that I wasn't clear. I can send emails with my ISP email however I cannot receive them. The error I posted was the error returned by my seperate Gmail account when I tried to send a email to the ISP email. I do not understand why it does this as I have not changed any settings on the ISP account and all details are corrects as I imported it form a previously working Windows Live account. Thanks.

Comment: Did you send the email from the Gmail website, or through Windows Mail? // Also, could you tell me the domain name of your address? (the part after `@`) If not, could you check if `nslookup -q=mx thedomain.tld` shows Google in the "mail exchanger" lines?

Answer (score 0):

Close Windows Mail, then log in from the web (to your Gmail account), send an email to your own Gmail address, then log out, launch Windows Mail, and try again.